# Is there a default/core File Manager provided by X11 or Debian?

Tags: debian, x11, file-manager

I recently installed Debian without a desktop environment. Currently, I'm using OpenBox in X11 and have yet to install a File Manager. I've found that in, seemingly all, programs capable of opening or saving files, there is a very GTK looking (to me) file manager/dialog that appears. The dialog appears to be consistent across programs and has got me wondering if and what "program" is being utilized here. Is the dialog packaged with the programs using it, or is there a "universal" file manager that either X11 or Debian (or any Linux distro for that matter) will revert to in the event there is no File Manager installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there is a very GTK looking (to me) file manager/dialog that appears.

What you're looking at is a default/standard GTK file open/save dialog ([GTK2](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html)/[GTK3](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html)), however

> is there a "universal" file manager that either X11 or Debian (or any Linux distro for that matter) will revert to in the event there is no File Manager installed?

No, there's no universal GTK file manager to speak of. Each major GTK based desktop environment offers its own file manager. In terms of the number and size of dependencies the lightest is probably Thunar (which is the default file manager for XFCE).